# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'

Tags: python, sublimetext3, atom-editor

El problema que tengo es que tengo un pryecto MVC y al ejecutar en atom o sublimetext me sale error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'

Pero al ejecutarlo desde visual studio code si me funciona bien. Como hago para que me funcione en esos editores de texto que me producen error.

Mi proyecto contiene las siguientes carpetas:

MVC:

```
controller:
   frmAlumnos.py
entity:
   Alumno.py
model:
   ColeccionAlumnos.py
view:
   frmAlumnos.ui
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QTableWidgetItem
sys.path.append(".")
from model.ColeccionAlumnos import ColeccionAlumnos
from entity.Alumno import Alumno
objColeccionAlumnos=ColeccionAlumnos()
class frmAlumnos(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("view/frmAlumnos.ui",self)
        self.btnGrabar.clicked.connect(self.grabar)

    def grabar(self):
        codigo=self.lneCodigo.text()
        nombre=self.lneNombre.text()
        nota1=int(self.spbNota1.text())
        nota2=int(self.spbNota2.text())
        objAlumno=Alumno(codigo,nombre,nota1,nota2)
        posicion=objColeccionAlumnos.buscar(codigo)
        if posicion==-1:
            objColeccionAlumnos.agregar(objAlumno)
        else:
            objColeccionAlumnos.modificar(objAlumno,posicion)
        self.listar()

    def listar(self):
        numeroElementos=objColeccionAlumnos.longitud()
        self.tblAlumnos.setRowCount(numeroElementos)
        for i in range(numeroElementos):
            self.tblAlumnos.setItem(i,0,QTableWidgetItem(objColeccionAlumnos.obtener(i).codigo))
            self.tblAlumnos.setItem(i,1,QTableWidgetItem(objColeccionAlumnos.obtener(i).nombre))
            self.tblAlumnos.setItem(i,2,QTableWidgetItem(str(objColeccionAlumnos.obtener(i).nota1)))
            self.tblAlumnos.setItem(i,3,QTableWidgetItem(str(objColeccionAlumnos.obtener(i).nota2)))
            self.tblAlumnos.setItem(i,2,QTableWidgetItem(str(objColeccionAlumnos.obtener(i).CalcularPromedio())))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui=frmAlumnos()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Al añadir a `sys.path(".")` no estás añadiendo rutas absolutas. ¿Desde qué directorio ejecutas el código?

Comment: la carpeta que contiene a todas las subcarpetas se llama "MVC" y yo estoy ejecutando el codigo desde el archivo frmAlumnos.py que esta dentro de la carpeta "controller".Al principio de mi comentario esta las carpetas y subcarpetas.

Comment: Python siempre añade el directorio del script que se está ejecutando a la ruta de búsqueda (sys.path), por lo que no sirve de nada el `sys.path.append(".")`. Seguramente, pylance (vscode) esté añadiendo el directorio del proyecto al sys.path y por eso te funciona.

Comment: Como podria solucionar este problema. Cuales son los pasos a seguir.

Comment: este es mi directorio:                                         
D:\Irbin\PROGRAMACIÓN\IDAT\II CICLO\ESTRUCTURA DE DATOS Y PROGRAMACION ORIENTADA A OBJETOS\POO PRACTICAS\SEMANA 11

Comment: Yo no puedo replicar el problema que tienes. No uso ni sublime ni atom, sólo vscode, y con él dices que funciona. ¿Has probado a ejecutarlo desde la línea de comandos?

Comment: si he probado y de igual forma me sale lo mismo.